# Placing balls into bins given certain restrictions

Tags: combinatorics

I wish to place $3$ balls into $5$ bins given the following restrictions:

Let the term $n$-chain denote $n$ chains of balls. Example: $1001000100$ where we take'$1001001$' but we *ignore* the 1's. Only consider the 0's. So '$00-000$' pretty much. The is a $2-chain$ since there are $2$ blocks of $0$'s chained together!

Let $b$-length denote the length of a block of $0$'s. Example: $1001000100$ where the $b$-length of $1001$ is $2$.

Example: The $b$-length of the $2$-chain $'10010001'$ is 5.

**Restriction:** The $b$-lengths of any two $n$-chains must be at most $1$.

---

The total number of ways to place $3$ balls into $5$ bins where a bin is allowed to be empty is $\binom{3+5-1}{5-1}$.

I am struggling on handling the restriction. I want to count how many I can place blocks of balls next to each other but where the difference between those two blocks is more than $1$.

Ideas?

Comment: Can you please clarify the restrictions on placing the balls? I cannot understand what you are saying about the 'chains' of balls.

Comment: @shardulc Sure. I admit it is an odd terminology. ...where $b$-lengths and $n$-chains represent the length of a block of $0$'s and chains of $n$ amount of $0$ blocks respectively.

Comment: Sorry, but how do 'chains' relate to balls? And what are blocks?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your restriction, but since there are only $\binom{7}{4} = 35$ possibilities without the restriction, you can just list all of them and count (yourself or with a computer) how many of them satisfy your restriction.

The question becomes more interesting if you want a formula (exact or asymptotic) for more general versions of the problem.

Comment: Yes, the question I am really aiming to answer is the general case. I can of course list it case-by-case for the above case. If someone was able to answer this question, I was hoping it would lead me to answer the general case. I suspect that a sequence to create is unique up to shift.